# Conversion of barbituric acid to veronal

Tags: organic-chemistry, drugs

This is just out of curiosity. I have no intention or authority to do conversions.

I am studying chemistry of tranquilizers, in that an important class is of barbiturates, which are also hypnotics. The structure of Barbituric acid and veronal, are similar, except veronal has two ethyl groups instead of hydrogen at lone $sp^3$ hybridised carbon. How can I convert Barbituric acid to veronal?

I thought that making carbocation or carbanion will help, but I don't think carbon will get negative or positive charge until nitrogen has hydrogen. Probably we'll have to protect nitrogens, am I thinking right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This paper from Tetrahedron Letters [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0040403901006219) details synthetic procedures using carbonyl compounds in solution with barbituric acid and Pt or Pd hydrogenation catalysyts to give reductive di-C alklyation. This includes examples of N-unsubstituted barbituric acids R1 = R2 = H. Using barbituric acid plus acetaldehyde should give you veronal in a single step.

[image]

Comment: What's the mechanism? (I don't have access to the paper)

Comment: Neither do I but my guess is aldol-type condensation of the active methylene followed by reduction of the double bond then a second similar condensation/reduction

Comment: @user55119  Thank you. I could only see the abstract of the TL paper.

Comment: @Waylander: I looked at the TL paper. Reductive monoalkylation with ketones and aliphatic/aromatic aldehydes works. Double alkylation only occurs reductively in the presence of strong acid with aromatic aldehydes. Although no mechanism was given, after monoalkylation, the benzylic alcohol formed from reduction of the aryl aldehyde forms a cation in acid and is alkylated by the enol of the monoalkylated product. This procedure will permit monoethylation but not the introduction of 2 ethyl groups.

Comment: @user55119 I wasn't able to get the whole of your comment, I understood firat part but second part of your seemed to be enigmatic. Can you please explain in a more elaborate way...

Comment: Symmetrical reductive dialkylation in the Waylander link only works with aromatic aldehydes sometimes in the presence of H2SO4. For barbituric acid itself, condensation occurs followed by hydrogenation. This monoalkylated species can undergo acid catalyzed aldolization followed by hydrogenolysis of the benzylic alcohol leading to the dibenzylated product. After some more thought, the cation I previous suggested is less likely. Aliphatic aldehydes only give monoalkylation because the penultimate aldol cmpd. cannot undergo hydrogenolysis. The formation of veranol this way appears unlikely.